# How to set a unique way to read and write in binary for C++?

Tags: c++, character-encoding, binary

I am creating an application that handles vectors.
As my vector only uses limited types of characters, I wanted to minimize the data amount of my output as much as possible.
For example, can I create a unique way of encoding and decoding binary so that
A is 00
B is 01
C is 10
D is 11
and "BADC" can be expressed with "01001110"?
Additionally, will a file encoded as above be 1 byte(+the file name etc)?

I used the normal way of encoding such as Utf and others but did not work out well for me.

Comment: `Additionally, will a file encoded as above be 1 byte(+the file name etc)?` 8 bits are 1 byte.

Comment: I was wondering if the 8 digit binary above can be registered as 1 byte if encoded in a unique way.

Comment: 8 binary digits are one byte.

Comment: Just write the bytes from std::string's data using https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write

Comment: So technically it is possible to register it as 1 byte? I was wondering if the OS would convert the 0 and 1s that was encoded by my program again to Binary by Ascii.

Comment: The *string* `"01001110"` is longer than `"ABCD"`. (If you store your encoding as text it will be twice as long as the original.) The *integer* that is 1001110 in binary – i.e. 78 – can be stored in just eight bits. Read about bitwise operations (in particular `|`) and shifting.

Comment: How big is your data?  Is this (potential) optimisation actually worth it?

Comment: I was expecting about 10^8  in Hexadecimal.

Comment: I did not quite read your question correctly. But for the most efficient way of coding strings with short binary representations have a look at huffman codes : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding. This will assign the shortest possible bit representation to your text.  It is tightly coupled to shannon's theorem about information density (entropy):  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory). Efficient as in least amount of data on disk (not necessarily efficient in speed)